# after interview, interviewers reply

Tags: meaning-in-context

after interview I sent one thank you letter also regarding the feed back of the interview to the interviewer. He reply me like this "We have shortlisted you and shall call you soon".
Is this a positive answer or negative?
I can't understand

Comment: It's a positive answer.  It means they had a long list of candidates to interview, and from that they put together a short list of only those whom they liked.  You're on that list.

Comment: @deadrat It is one of many typical answers a potential employer gives to an applicant even if they already decided to drop him/her.  It doesn't necessarily mean they will call you. You never know from that message. Only one thing is certain. *Wait until I call you. (Don't bother me with this kind of a question any more). If you are not called, sorry*.

Comment: The language makes it a positive response.  (A negative response would be "You're no longer under consideration.")  I should have pointed out that not all positive responses are true, and the interviewer may have been kind but untruthful.

Comment: @deadrat No employer has an obligation to be truthful to applicatns as no applicant will be 100% truthful about everything. They do lie with that kind of message of "I will call you within a week" because they don't want to explain the reason why and applicants will know the *truth* when the deadline (to call) comes.

Comment: My comment was about the language.  Since nowhere do I claim or imply that employers have any obligation to tell applicants the truth, you may have the last word on this exchange as well.

Comment: @deadrat I don't think it is necessarily a positive answer (you are the one who commented *it is a positive answer* in the first comment). I  explained the reasons why in other comments.

Comment: Technically it's a "positive" answer, meaning you've moved to the next stage of consideration.  But, of course, it's not unusual for such answers to be given to most people, just to avoid negative "vibes", so don't get your hopes up *too* much.  ("Shortlisted" simply means your name has moved from the long list of applicants to the shorter list of those to be considered further in the next states of the hiring process.)

Answer (score 1):

I presume the only word that you didn't understand was 'shortlist'. You could have found its meaning by searching online, e.g https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=shortlist+definition

When the process started, there was a *long list* of candidates (maybe hundreds applied). This has been reduced to a *short list* of candidates (perhaps four or five).

There is a possibility that you will be called for another interview. This will allow them to choose between the remaining shortlisted candidates.  If you want the job and you are recalled then now is the time to start thinking about why they would want you. They already know you have the right skills and they already like you. Now they have to decide what makes one out of the remaining few the most suited to the job. They may ask different types of question.